# Is it possible to show a breakdown of actual clock intervals in a clock table?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock, org-clock-table

The clock table is great for an overview of what I did over the day/week. But I would also like to see *when* in the day I performed the specific task.

It would be great if I can see the actual clock entries for the day/week in the clock table overview as well, similar to what I see in the agenda log view. Having them in two separate views is a bit inconvenient.

Using the `:timestamp t` option shows all sorts of other timestamps, just not the actual CLOCK timestamps...

Comment: Interesting question! did you find a solution in the meantime, then pleast post it as an answer!